# Im getting gyp error when installing packages

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

I tried installing the newest version of node and installing windows build tools, but they both are not working. This is the first time I've encountered this error and I don't know how to fix it. Everything worked yesterday, but today the problem appeared.

```html
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
gyp info using node@16.16.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "C:\Python310\python.e
xe"
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/node-v16.16.0-headers.
tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/node-v16.16.0-headers.
tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/win-x64/node.lib
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/win-arm64/node.lib
gyp http 404 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/win-arm64/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.16.0/win-x64/node.lib
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32630.194) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modu
les\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\
nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
```

Comment: How did you install windows build tools

Comment: npm install -g windows-build-tools. I saw this as reccomened way to solve the problem

Comment: it says "not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8" this means you installed and old version of windows build tools . i got the gyp error last week and this solved it ` npm install --global --production windows-build-tools `

Comment: maybe add the production thing it would work

Comment: "could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use " or consider downgrading node version